# Delphi 2007 and Windows 7: Debugger fails to stop host application

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007

I'm running Delphi 2007 with Windows 7 Ultimate.

The code I'm working on compiles to a DLL file. To use Delphi's debugger I launch a standard EXE application via Delphis' Run command. The application loads the DLL file and the debugger is automatically attached to the correct process.

The problem occurs when resetting the host application (Delphi->Run->Program Reset). The host application hangs in the final stages of closing.

The application can be stopped via the task manager, but this takes 1-2 minutes and is a real work flow killer.

Is anyone else having the same problem and is there a fix for it? I've googled but not found anything.

**System Specs**

- Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550 @ 2.83 GHz
- Ram 2GB DDR2
- Motherboard ASUS P5Q-E (LGA775)
- Video card ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT (gigabyte)

Answer (score 1):

What does the host application do? 
  Has it some threads that need to finish?
  Is it waiting for response of the dll that you are debugging?

If the host application is your own, try to debug it and see whats happens when you reset it from the debugger. It is most probably waiting for something, when it's waiting for your dll then be sure to hit run before you try to close it.

Success

Comment: The host application is not mine. AFAIK my dll doesn't contain any blocking code. So I don't think the host should be waiting on it.

Comment: Using an older computer running Windows XP, but otherwise the exactly the same software, Delphi did not hang like this.

Comment: Since it's running fine with another OS setup, see if any security stuff is causing it, a virus scanner aor something like thta.